# In Visual Studio I get a green wavy line underneath HTML tags for all my pages

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

In a ASP.net project I'm working on right now with Visual Studio 2013 I'm getting a green wavy line underneath the html tag for all the .aspx pages that are part of the project.

To determine what exactly is the issue, I'm playing around with the project as well as starting a new project from scratch to see what exactly the issue is. This is what I've discovered so far.

- With the current project I'm working on, the green line always appear underneath the html tag even when I create a new .aspx page from scratch. Underneath is a screen shot of the new page I created. The error I get reads "Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional:  content is not supported outside 'script' or 'asp:content' regions"

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70RBz.png)

- The same green line appears underneath all the html tags for all other .aspx pages in the project with the same error message, including the master page. Pages that do NOT inherit from the master page and has a html tag also has the same error.
- Curiously, if i start a page that is a html page rather then an .aspx page the html tag in this case doesn't not have the error

When I start a new project from scratch that does nothing more then print "Hello, World!" to a webpage, I notice the following behavior:

- The html tag in the master page does not have the green line underneath like it does in the older project
- Other aspx pages that inherit from the master page are error free unless I put a html tag in it. Based on what I've read about master pages and pages that derive from them that is standard behavior.

Any thoughts on what is causing the green line to appear under the html tag for the aspx pages in the project I am working on? My first thought was that it was a HTML validation thing so I tried validating the pages with different HTML validation versions and the error still remains. I have a feeling that the fact that the html tag in the master page is getting this error is the key to all of this.

Comment: Is the page in the screenshot supposed to be a content page? Was this project upgraded from a previous version of Visual Studio (and/or WebForms)?

Comment: The page in the screen shot is not a content page and does not inherit from the master page. Every aspx page that is part of the project has this error if there is a html tag present in the page regardless of it's relationship with the master page.

The project was built from scratch and was not upgraded from older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it on my own. Turns out I just had to go to the Web.Config file and delete the masterPageFile= "(location of master page here") attribute between the `<page>` tags.